# Akka Cluster Types

Tags: akka, distributed-computing, akka-cluster

I am trying to understand how clustering works in Akka. Specifically I'm interested in two different types of clustering:

- **Heterogenous** nodes, where each "node" (JVM) in the cluster contains a mixture of different Actors; and
- **Homogenous** nodes, where each nodecontains all the same types of Actors

[image]

Above are examples of what I mean by *heterogenous* and *homogenous* nodes. In the first (top) diagram, an `all-actors.jar` is deployed to three machines: `myapp01`, `myapp02` and an AWS machine. In the second (bottom) diagram, 3 different types of Actor Systems are deployed; 1 to each machine. The heterogenous model has the benefits of simplicity and makes the Actor System as a whole scalable. The homogenous model allows for finer-grained elasticity (perhaps we need 3x more "B" Actors than "A" or "C", etc.).

1. Are both types of clustering (heterogenous and homogenous) supported by Akka? If not, what would be needed (added on top of existing clustering) to obtain these clustering strategies? If so, how is each type configured?
2. Is it possible to control the number of Actors you want in each node? Is it possible to say "*On `myapp01` I want 500 A-Actors, 200 B-Actors and 1,000 C-Actors*"? Or does Akka just respond to messaging demand and scale up/down the various Actors automagically?

Comment: *Nobody* on SO has ever used Akka clustering before?!?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, it turns out the Akka clustering has nothing to do with clustering Actor Systems across JVMs, but it essentially keeps the data of each Actor in a synchronized, in-memory cache so that if the thread executing the Actor is interrupted or dies, the Actor's data can be used to regenerate a new thread running the same type of Actor.

So Akka Clustering is like [Eraser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eraser_(film)) but instead of for Hollywood actors, for Akka actors.

Comment: It is for clustering actor systems across JVMs.  See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/cluster-usage.html

Comment: Thanks @sourcedelica (+1) - however that only appears to be the case for the Scala binding; the Java binding doesn't seem to work that way. Even in that link you sent, there is no mention of either *homogenous* or *heterogenous* clusters.

Comment: There is no specific support for what you are calling homogenous/heterogenous clusters in Akka but you can definitely run these types of clusters using Akka.  Akka clustering is basically a group membership facility, but there are other pieces of functionality built on top of that.  For example, using roles and cluster-aware routers you can build your own homogeneous/heterogeneous clusters.

Comment: Thanks again @sourcedelica (+1) - very interesting... I can't seem to find either notion of "roles" or "cluster-aware routers" in the Akka docs...do you know where I could read up on these? Thanks again!

Comment: They are both discussed in the Cluster reference page http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/cluster-usage.html